# sql request - multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
userid    title         content
1         gender        male
1         location      NY    
2         gender        female
2         location      SF
3         gender        female
3         location      NY
```

I'm trying to retrieve only userid with **gender="male" and location="NY"**

if I try:

```
select userid
from table
where content="male"
   AND location="NY";
```

It will return null.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: BTW: This is a bad idea for a table structure. If at all possible I'd suggest rearchitecting it.

Comment: I know but it was designed this way some times ago.

Comment: I know what it's like to get stuck with legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.userId
FROM yourTable AS t
INNER JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t.userId = t2.userId
   AND t.title = 'gender'
   AND t.content = 'male'
   AND t2.title = 'location'
   AND t2.content = 'NY'
```

I would also consider looking at normalizing your data.  It would make queries like this much easier (and probably faster) in the future.

Comment: beat me by 35 seconds. Hate when that happens. Need to learn to type faster on these softball questions. +1

Comment: @JohnFx I definitely know how that goes, I've been too slow on many questions already tonight.